# Innodb cluster options missing

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster

I have successfully installed and run an INNODB Cluster on mysql 8.0.19

However I cannot set options for the cluster

when we run

```
cluster=dba.getCluster();
cluster.options();
```

We get the following error

```
Invalid object member options (AttributeError)
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What MySQL Shell version are you using?

`<Cluster>.options()` was introduced in version 8.0.14:

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-innodb-cluster-changing-cluster-options-live/

Comment: Thank you that is the Answer, even though I had latest version of MySql the shell was an older version